# Lists and alphabetical restraints

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, input

I am trying to write a program that asks the user for a list of names and prints those names that start with letters A through M.  My current code returns a TypeError and says that 'NoneType' is not iterable.

```
lst = print(input('Enter a list of names: '))
alpha = ['a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M']
for x in alpha:
    if x in lst:
        print(x)
```

Thanks

Comment: `print()` returns `None`. So, `lst` is `None`. (Also, there are quite a few other issues, but that is the root of your current problem).

Comment: That’s a list with just a single item.

Comment: In alpha, you must put quotes around each letter. Also yes, don't use print with input or raw_input.

Answer (score 0):

First, no need to re-create the alphabet, it is already done in python's `string.ascii_lowercase` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html))

Second, you need to use `raw_input` if you want to give multiple strings separated by a space, and then, you need to split it so that you get a list of names which you can iterate on, check if contains, and so on.

Here below, two different ways of doing what you asked for:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_lowercase

lst = raw_input('Enter a list of names: ')
names = lst.split()

by_first_letter = defaultdict(list)
for name in names:
    by_first_letter[name[0]].append(name)

for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    if by_first_letter[letter]:
        print letter, by_first_letter[letter]
```

Another solution:

```
names = lst.split()
for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    matches = [name for name in names if name.startswith(letter)]
    if matches:
        print letter, matches
```

---

update: easier and faster solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

by_first_letter = defaultdict(list)
for name in raw_input('Enter a list of names: ').split():
    by_first_letter[name[0]].append(name)

for letter, names in by_first_letter.items():
    print letter, names
```

Comment: i didnt downvote but the first solution prints each letter on its own line (A-Z) followed by [ ]. the second solution prints nothing. simply, im still confused

Comment: both print the proper results, however, I just added an "if" to print only if there are names starting with the letter

Comment: None of this explains the problem in the OP's original code, or what the benefits of your suggested solutions are

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

On line 4 of your code you have written:

```
if x in lst:
```

Using the reserved work `in` means that you want to check if `x` is present in the list `lst`. The way Python will do this for you is to "iterate" over the list (meaning compare it to each item one by one). The error saying it is not "iterable" is because it is trying to treat `lst` as a list but it isn't one.

I have made an alteration below to do what I think you are looking for:

```
lst = input('Enter a list of names: ').split(" ")
alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m']
for x in lst:
    if x[0].lower() in alpha:
        print(x)
```

Example:

```
INPUT: Andrew Matthew Zain
OUTPUT: Andrew
        Matthew
```

The loop is splitting the user input at every space which means `lst` will actually be a list. You are then going to grab the first character using the shortform `x[0]` and then check if it is present in `alpha`.